# How to display Plot.ly Modebar Icons in a horizontal Row

Tags: css, plotly, plotly.js

I added a simple plotly chart to my Wordpress website, and the modebar (i.e. the icon toolbox) is displayed as a block on the upper right hand side of the chart ([link here](https://www.1screener.com/home/)).

How can I *instead* make the modebar display as a horizontal row, as shown in the Plot.ly documentation [link here](https://plotly.com/javascript/configuration-options/#force-the-modebar-to-always-be-visible)?

I have already tried to alter various of the CSS settings for the elements `.modebar` and `.modebar-container` but wasn't able to solve the problem.

Thank you for any ideas and suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution: the WordpRess theme I am using, "TwentyTwenty" style.css messes up the Plot.ly modebar with the following setting:

```
svg, img, embed, object {
    display: block;
}
```

Rectification is rather simple, as follows:

```
svg {
    display: inherit;
}
```